# Is the "vector grid" tool not working?

Tags: qgis, qgis-processing, vector-grid

I am trying to create a vector grid (polygons) but the tool `Vector`>`Research Tools`>`Vector grid` lets QGIS crash all the time. I tried different grid extents (same as canvas, by another layer), resolutions, opened a blank project ... but it keeps on crashing.

I am using the newest QGIS 2.18.3

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm using QGIS 2.18.3 and it works well for me.

You may try checking two things:

1. Check if you are in a Projected Coordinate System;
2. Take care of the units of measurement for spacing: the **Vector grid** tool uses `0.0001` by default for both X and Y spacing, so it may cause a crash of QGIS due to the huge number of features are being created.

Comment: For completeness, the default value makes sense for CRS using degrees, but not for those using meters or feet as units.

Comment: Thank you for the quick answers! The problem was the grids resolution/spacing. Although I already thought that the default spacing was to small, the highest spacing I tried out was 5m. Apparently, this was still to small considering the extent (3435259.5439,3439679.5439,5412210.3201,5420470.3201). Now with  20m it works.

Comment: I'm glad it worked for you!